# Speed-up computation on sub-matrices of a 4D tensor

Tags: python, numpy

I have an array whose input data is 1028* 24* 24*16. When I run the code below, it works very slowly. How can I speed this up? thanks

(I want to get 3*3 matrices from a large array.)

```
import itertools,math,time,random
import numpy as np

start=time.time()

def ls(x):
     x_p = x / np.sum(x)         
     return np.max(x_p)

inputs = np.random.rand(1028, 24, 24, 16)
b, r, c, ch = inputs.shape[0], inputs.shape[1], inputs.shape[2], inputs.shape[3]

inputs = np.transpose(inputs, (0, 3, 1, 2)) 
inputs = np.reshape(inputs, (b*ch, r, c))

s=2
r=3
num_r=9
num_c=9
ke = np.zeros((b*ch, num_r, num_c), dtype=np.float32)

for i in range(num_r):
     for j in range(num_c):
         outs = np.array(list(map(ls, inputs[:, i*s:i*s+r, j*s:j*s+r])))
         ke[:, i, j] = outs

ke = np.reshape(ke, (b, ch, num_r, num_c))
ke = np.transpose(ke, (0, 2, 3, 1))

print(time.time() - start)
```

Comment: Try adding [numba](https://numba.pydata.org/). It can make miracles with poorly optimized sequential code

Comment: @MichaelSzczesny A 3*3 matrix that I send to the ls method. I meant it.

Comment: @ZaeroDivide How can I include numba. what should I do? where should i include it?

Comment: @MichaelSzczesny I updated the question. can you check again

Comment: @merve just check numba link. Project page explains everything better than I could

Comment: @MichaelSzczesny No, I only added 1 method. everything else is the same. Unfortunately, this method is very slow. maybe the problem is not from the method, but from the for which I call the method. I don't know and I need help. thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The original code can be wrapped (with some polishing) into the following function:

```py
import numpy as np


def foo0(arr, s=2, r=3, nr=9, nc=9):
    forward_axes = (0, 3, 1, 2)
    backward_axes = (0, 2, 3, 1)
    b, r, c, ch = arr.shape
    arr = np.transpose(arr, forward_axes) 
    arr = np.reshape(arr, (b * ch, r, c))
    result = np.zeros((b * ch, nr, nc), dtype=np.float32)
    for i in range(nr):
        for j in range(nc):
            result[:, i, j] = np.fromiter(
                map(
                    lambda x: np.max(x / np.sum(x)),
                    arr[:, i * s:i * s + r, j * s:j * s + r]),
                dtype=np.float32)
    result = np.reshape(result, (b, ch, nr, nc))
    result = np.transpose(result, backward_axes)
    return result
```

While the explicit looping suggests that Numba could be applied here to get some low-hanging fruit, unfortunately the function cannot be readily decorated without interaction with Python object, thus greatly reducing the speed-up.
Fortunately, the core computation can be readily vectorized and, as long as `nr` and `nc` are small enough, this optimization is sufficient:

```py
def foo1(arr, s=2, r=3, nr=9, nc=9):
    forward_axes = (0, 3, 1, 2)
    backward_axes = (0, 2, 3, 1)
    b, r, c, ch = arr.shape
    arr = np.transpose(arr, forward_axes) 
    arr = np.reshape(arr, (b * ch, r, c))
    result = np.zeros((b * ch, nr, nc), dtype=np.float32)
    for i in range(nr):
        for j in range(nc):
            x = arr[:, i * s:i * s + r, j * s:j * s + r]
            result[:, i, j] = np.max(x, (-1, -2)) / np.sum(x, (-1, -2))
    result = np.reshape(result, (b, ch, nr, nc))
    result = np.transpose(result, backward_axes)
    return result
```

(The above `foo1()` is essentially equivalent to [@ymmx's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72462171/5218354) with some additional optimizations.)

Note that `max(x / k)` is the same as `max(x) / k` but the number of divisions are greatly reduced.

Actually, transposing and reshaping, while it may help with the computation speed, it is not really necessary:

```py
def foo2(arr, s=2, r=3, nr=9, nc=9):
    b, r, c, ch = arr.shape
    result = np.zeros((b, nr, nc, ch), dtype=np.float32)
    for i in range(nr):
        for j in range(nc):
            x = arr[:, i * s:i * s + r, j * s:j * s + r, :]
            result[:, i, j, :] = np.max(x, (1, 2)) / np.sum(x, (1, 2))
    return result
```

The above is simpler to translate in Numba, but the speed gain for small `nr`/`nc` would be minimal (compared to the partially vectorized approach):

```py
import numba as nb


@nb.njit
def sum_nb(arr):
    result = 0
    for x in arr:
        result += x
    return result


@nb.njit
def max_nb(arr):
    result = arr[0]
    for x in arr[1:]:
        if x > result:
            result = x
    return result


@nb.njit
def _sum_max(arr):
    b, r, c, ch = arr.shape
    res = np.empty((b, ch), dtype=arr.dtype)
    for i in range(b):
        for j in range(ch):
            x = arr[i, :, :, j].ravel()
            res[i, j] = max_nb(x) / sum_nb(x)
    return res


@nb.njit
def foo3(arr, s=2, r=3, nr=9, nc=9):
    b, r, c, ch = arr.shape
    result = np.zeros((b, nr, nc, ch), dtype=np.float32)
    for i in range(nr):
        for j in range(nc):
            result[:, i, j, :] = _sum_max(arr[:, i * s:i * s + r, j * s:j * s + r, :])
    return result
```

Another option would be to keep the Numba-incompatible code outside of the main looping:

```py
@nb.njit(fastmath=True)
def _foo4(arr, result, s, r, nr, nc):
    bch, nr, nc = result.shape
    for i in range(nr):
        for j in range(nc):
            for k in range(bch):
                x = arr[k, i * s:i * s + r, j * s:j * s + r].ravel()
                result[k, i, j] = max_nb(x) / sum_nb(x)
    return result


def foo4(arr, s=2, r=3, nr=9, nc=9):
    forward_axes = (0, 3, 1, 2)
    backward_axes = (0, 2, 3, 1)
    b, r, c, ch = arr.shape
    arr = np.transpose(arr, forward_axes) 
    arr = np.reshape(arr, (b * ch, r, c))
    result = np.empty((b * ch, nr, nc))
    result = _foo4(arr, result, s, r, nr, nc)
    result = np.reshape(result, (b, ch, nr, nc))
    result = np.transpose(result, backward_axes)
    return result
```

but again the speed gain would be minimal.

Note that a fully vectorized approach is unlikely to be efficient, because the objects inside the main loops are jagged.

To get some ideas of the relative speed:

```py
funcs = foo0, foo1, foo2, foo3, foo4
arr = np.random.rand(100, 24, 24, 16)


timeds_n = {}
for p in range(1):
    n = 10 ** p
    k = 3
    arr = np.random.rand(100, 24, 24, 16)
    print(f"N = {arr.size}")
    base = funcs[0](arr)
    timeds_n[n] = []
    for func in funcs:
        res = func(arr)
        timed = %timeit -r 1 -n 1 -q -o func(arr)
        timeds_n[n].append(timed.best)
        print(f"{func.__name__:>24}  {np.allclose(base, res)}  {timed.best:.9f}")
```

```py
N = 921600
                    foo0  True  1.757508748
                    foo1  True  0.095540081
                    foo2  True  0.179208341
                    foo3  True  0.160671403
                    foo4  True  0.155691721
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply. what if i get 3*3 matrices from the loop every time. Let's call this value x. as a return

mask=[[4,8,1],[2,0,2],[6,8,4]]
return np.sum(np.where(x >= x[1][1], 1, 0)*mask)*x.max()

I want to use the formula how do i do this?

Comment: @merve it may be possible to do something with strides, but you should try to ask a question with more details.

Comment: def ls(x):
      x_p = x / np.sum(x)
      return np.max(x_p)
I want to use the method below instead of the method. I am actually sending a 3*3 matrix to the method and I want to do the following operation on this matrix. Unfortunately, I couldn't adapt it to your code.

return np.sum(np.where(x >= x[1][1], 1, 0)*[[4,8,1],[2,0,2],[6,8,4]] )*x.max()

Comment: @merve Please ask a new question (perhaps linking this one, tagging me in comment). Comments are ineffective for you to providing enough information and for me (and others) to attempt an answer. Also, if you think the question in the original post to be answered, please consider accepting one of the answers.

Comment: I opened a new topic [link]https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72490532/how-can-we-speed-up-tensorflow-layer

Answer (score 2):

I think the issue is mainly the function ls which should be vectorized and the list / map that takes you time

```
import itertools,math,time,random
import numpy as np

start=time.time()

def ls(x):
     x_p = x / np.sum(np.sum(x, axis=1), axis=1)[:,None,None]
     return np.max(np.max(x_p,axis=1),axis=1)

inputs = np.random.rand(1028, 24, 24, 16)
b, r, c, ch = inputs.shape[0], inputs.shape[1], inputs.shape[2], inputs.shape[3]

inputs = np.transpose(inputs, (0, 3, 1, 2))
inputs = np.reshape(inputs, (b*ch, r, c))

s=2
r=3
num_r=9
num_c=9
ke = np.zeros((b*ch, num_r, num_c), dtype=np.float32)

for i in range(num_r):
    print(i)
    for j in range(num_c):
        # outs = np.array(list(map(ls, inputs[:, i*s:i*s+r, j*s:j*s+r])))
        outs =  ls(inputs[:, i*s:i*s+r, j*s:j*s+r])
        ke[:, i, j] = outs

ke = np.reshape(ke, (b, ch, num_r, num_c))
ke = np.transpose(ke, (0, 2, 3, 1))

print(time.time() - start)
```

Comment: Shouldn't you verify whether "this version works" by comparing the output (and the performance) to the original?

Comment: I checked: this does seem to be about 20 times faster than OP's code, and `np.allclose()` verifies the result. :)

Comment: Twice as fast if you reduce over both axes in *ls*: `return (x / x.sum((1,2), keepdims=True)).max((1,2))`.

Comment: @ymmx this code will not work. because with list(map... I get the array in order. Your code example doesn't have this unfortunately. In each list(map example, the ls method is called 16448 times. Whereas in your code it is called only once).

Comment: @AKX Where and how am I supposed to use np.allclose()? Thanks

Comment: Yes, the optimisation is based on this. The ls is called once but it gives directly the 16448 answers

Comment: `np.allclose()` is a function to see if two matrices are identical (within a certain tolerance), You compute both versions in the nested for loop and after, you can compare both results with the function.